# Why not create github.io (github page)

Tags: github-pages

I have created github page.
0
URL : https://github.com/khkong/khkong.github.io

When I access my page, I get a 404 error. I can not find the site. (https://khkong.github.io)

There seems to be a limit to the creation. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a GitHub-page, the URL is `https://adarkhero.github.io/PROJECTNAME/` - So, try adding the name of your project to the URL (Like `https://khkong.github.io/testproject`). You can also see the link to your GitHub-page in the settings of your repository.

Comment: Yeah, According to the guthub URL that guides you when you access my page, it's called the project page. I simply want to create a user page.  https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/

Comment: And I've had it made before. Modernity is not made now. I do not know why.

Comment: Try naming your repository "khkong", without the .github.io.

Comment: Thanks. You change it to khkong as you say and then change it to khkong.github.io again. It seems to be a temporary bug.